# Google rich card Javascript throws error

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to add a Google rich card to my E-Commerce shop Product page.

```
     <script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Product",
  "name": $('#<%=lblProductTitle.ClientID %>').text();,
  "image": "http://www.example.com/anvil_executive.jpg",
  "description": "Sleeker than ACME's Classic Anvil, the Executive Anvil is perfect for the business traveller looking for something to drop from a height.",
  "mpn": "925872",
  "brand": {
    "@type": "Thing",
    "name": "ACME"
  },
  "aggregateRating": {
 -----------
     ----------
  },
  "offers": {
  -----------
     ----------
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

My website is built on Asp.net and hence I have to access product name with clientId property. Everything looks ok to me. But when i check the page here https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool it throws an error like this
[image]
on line

```
  "name": $('#<%=lblProductTitle.ClientID %>').text();,
```

To confirm my id selector works properly, I tried something like this

```
$(document).ready(function() { $('#<%=lblProductTitle.ClientID %>').text() });
```

And it alerts correct product name. Can any one point out what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: `"name": $('#<%=lblProductTitle.ClientID %>').text(),`  try it. Remove semi-colon

Comment: @Anant already tried, Still same error

Comment: pLEASE CHECK THIS:- `<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Product",
  "name": "MyNAME",
  "image": "http://www.example.com/anvil_executive.jpg",
  "description": "Sleeker than ACME's Classic Anvil, the Executive Anvil is perfect for the business traveller looking for something to drop from a height.",
  "mpn": "925872",
  "brand": {
    "@type": "Thing",
    "name": "ACME"
  }
}
</script>`. iT'S WORKING

Comment: PLEASE TRY IT IN "CODE SNIPPET" area  of the link:- https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool

Comment: @Anant it works for me too when I put a string instead of my IDselector. But I want my selector too to work as this is a dynamic website

Comment: @Anant it shows same error in "CODE SNIPPET" area.

Comment: @Anant for me it looks like , $ sign is not accepted in Rich card code

Comment: Actually your `$('#<%=lblProductTitle.ClientID %>').text(),` seems not working. try like this:- `var name = $('#<%=lblProductTitle.ClientID %>').text();`  and then provide this name here:- `"name": name,`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136149/discussion-between-athul-and-anant).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why did you use jquery for this?

EDIT: Google doesn't look javascript datas

Can you try like this?

`"name": $('#<%=lblProductTitle.ClientID %>').text();,` to =>

`"name": "<%=lblProductTitle.Text%>",`

```
 <script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context": "http://schema.org/",
      "@type": "Product",
      "name": "<%=lblProductTitle.Text%>",
      "image": "http://www.example.com/anvil_executive.jpg",
      "description": "Sleeker than ACME's Classic Anvil, the Executive Anvil is perfect for the business traveller looking for something to drop from a height.",
      "mpn": "925872",
      "brand": {
        "@type": "Thing",
        "name": "ACME"
      },
      "aggregateRating": {
     -----------
         ----------
      },
      "offers": {
      -----------
         ----------
        }
      }
    }
    </script>
```